# Noty (notification library) dialog has a transparent background - AngularJS Web Application

Tags: javascript, css, background, transparent, noty

I currently am in the process of making an AngularJS web application from scratch and am new to AngularJS, which is important to note because I could always be missing something fundamental.

**The issue is this:**

I have a fully functional Noty dialog that works exactly as it should aside from having no background. I installed Noty using `npm install noty` and included its JavaScript and CSS files in my index HTML file.

```
<link href="node_modules/noty/lib/noty.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="node_modules/noty/lib/noty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The CSS file's contents:

```
.noty_layout_mixin, #noty_layout__top, #noty_layout__topLeft, #noty_layout__topCenter, #noty_layout__topRight, #noty_layout__bottom, #noty_layout__bottomLeft, #noty_layout__bottomCenter, #noty_layout__bottomRight, #noty_layout__center, #noty_layout__centerLeft, #noty_layout__centerRight {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 9999999;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  max-width: 90%; }

#noty_layout__top {
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%; }

#noty_layout__topLeft {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 325px; }

#noty_layout__topCenter {
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 325px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-webkit-calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translate(calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1); }

#noty_layout__topRight {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 325px; }

#noty_layout__bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%; }

#noty_layout__bottomLeft {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 325px; }

#noty_layout__bottomCenter {
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 325px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-webkit-calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translate(calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1); }

#noty_layout__bottomRight {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 325px; }

#noty_layout__center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 325px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-webkit-calc(-50% - .5px), -webkit-calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translate(calc(-50% - .5px), calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1); }

#noty_layout__centerLeft {
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  width: 325px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -webkit-calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translate(0, calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1); }

#noty_layout__centerRight {
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  width: 325px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -webkit-calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
          transform: translate(0, calc(-50% - .5px)) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1); }

.noty_progressbar {
  display: none; }

.noty_has_timeout.noty_has_progressbar .noty_progressbar {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #646464;
  opacity: 0.2;
  filter: alpha(opacity=10); }

.noty_bar {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1);
      transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  overflow: hidden; }

.noty_effects_open {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(50%);
          transform: translate(50%);
  -webkit-animation: noty_anim_in 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          animation: noty_anim_in 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards; }

.noty_effects_close {
  -webkit-animation: noty_anim_out 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
          animation: noty_anim_out 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards; }

.noty_fix_effects_height {
  -webkit-animation: noty_anim_height 75ms ease-out;
          animation: noty_anim_height 75ms ease-out; }

.noty_close_with_click {
  cursor: pointer; }

.noty_close_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-out; }

.noty_close_button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.noty_modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 10000;
  opacity: .3;
  left: 0;
  top: 0; }

.noty_modal.noty_modal_open {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: noty_modal_in .3s ease-out;
          animation: noty_modal_in .3s ease-out; }

.noty_modal.noty_modal_close {
  -webkit-animation: noty_modal_out .3s ease-out;
          animation: noty_modal_out .3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards; }

@-webkit-keyframes noty_modal_in {
  100% {
    opacity: .3; } }

@keyframes noty_modal_in {
  100% {
    opacity: .3; } }

@-webkit-keyframes noty_modal_out {
  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes noty_modal_out {
  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes noty_modal_out {
  100% {
    opacity: 0; } }

@-webkit-keyframes noty_anim_in {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
    opacity: 1; } }

@keyframes noty_anim_in {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
            transform: translate(0);
    opacity: 1; } }

@-webkit-keyframes noty_anim_out {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(50%);
            transform: translate(50%);
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes noty_anim_out {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(50%);
            transform: translate(50%);
    opacity: 0; } }

@-webkit-keyframes noty_anim_height {
  100% {
    height: 0; } }

@keyframes noty_anim_height {
  100% {
    height: 0; } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=noty.css.map*/
```

The only other places I have seen this issue posted, the answer was just "You forgot to include CSS files." However, I have done a little digging and I don't see what I could be missing.

---

**Thank you in advance for suggestions/solutions**

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. I fixed it by adding the following two lines in my app.scss:

```
@import "~noty/src/noty.scss";
@import "~noty/src/themes/mint.scss";
```

Comment: I have the files noty.scss & mint.scss but not an app.scss. I used a file called style.css for app-wide styling. Would I just try the code you provided in there or do I need an app.scss file?